# why code execute superclass' method and not subclass'?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

im practicing polymorphism and inheritance stumbled upon a solution i can't understand

there's the following simple code:

```java
public class A{
    protected int _i;

    public A(int i){   
        _i = i;
    }

    public boolean equals (A other){
        System.out.print("A ");
        return ((other!=null) && (_i==other._i));
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public B(int i){
        super(i+1);
    }

    public boolean equals (B other){
        System.out.print("B ");
        return ((other!=null) && (_i==other._i));
    }
}

public class C extends B{
    public C(int i){
        super(i);
    }

    public boolean equals (Object other){
        System.out.print("C ");
        return ((other!=null) && (other instanceof C) && (_i==((C) other)._i));
    }
}

//main:

public class DriverABCD{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A(1);
        B b = new B(1);
        C c = new C(1);

        a=c;
        System.out.println (b.equals(a));  
    }
}
```

the output is A 'A true'. the problem is i don't get why.

from my understanding `a=c` makes 'a' a reference of object C (and the garbage collector deletes object A).

so `(b.equals(a))` goes to class B and execute equals(B other) since C extends B.

where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the *values* of `a`, `b` and `c` and think about what method you would call if you only knew the *types* involved.

`a` is an `A` and `b` is a `B`. You call a method named `equals` on a `B` and pass in an `A`. The method that best matches that call is `public boolean equals (A other)` in `A`.

Comment: that is logical yes, but the call for the method is made AFTER the line ```a=c```, so why does ```a``` still count as type A?

Comment: @EricParker no. `a` is still a variable of type `A`, it actually contains a `C`, but as far as the compiler is concerned (or someone looking only at the types) it simply is still an `A`, the value does not matter. If you wrote `a = null` the same logic applies, the value does not matter, the type you specified the variable to have is what matters.

Comment: alright that the piece of information i was missing. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are different. A takes A type, B takes B type, and C takes C type. The method has to have the same parameter to override.

```
public class A{
    protected int _i;

    public A(int i){   
        _i = i;
    }

    public boolean equals (Object other){
        System.out.print("A ");
        return ((other!=null) && (other instanceof A) && (_i== (A) other._i));
    }
}

   public class B extends A{
       public B(int i){
           super(i+1);
    }

    public boolean equals (Object other){
        System.out.print("B ");
        return ((other!=null) && (other instanceof C) && ((B) _i==other._i));
    }
}

public class C extends B{
    public C(int i){
        super(i);
    }

    public boolean equals (Object other){
        System.out.print("C ");
        return ((other!=null) && (other instanceof C) && (_i==((C) other)._i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `equals` method in class `B` has a different method signature than the `equals` method in class `A`. So class `B` is actually declaring a *completely new and separate* `equals` method, *not* overriding the `equals` method in class `A`.

If you want to override a method in the parent class, you have to use the same method signature. To see this in action, try adding this method to your class `B`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(A other) {
    System.out.print("B* ");
    return ((other != null) && (_i == other._i));
}
```

You will find that the output is `B* true`, which I think is what you expected in your first attempt.

To avoid confusion in the future, I recommend you always use the `@Override` annotation. If you tried to use this annotation on the original `equals` method in your `B` class, Java would report the following error:

```
The method equals(B) of type B must override a superclass method
```